# firebase cli tells me I have no emulators configured when I just successfully configured some

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to use the firebase emulator.

I have run *firebase init emulators* (selected an existing project) and the selected the emulators I want to init (firestore and auth).

It then says the the emulator initialization succeeded.

I then proceed to run *firebase emulators:start* and it says "no emulators initialized", even though the cli command JUST said that emulators were initialized.

Observe the complete output...

```
user@devmachine:~/src/firebase-emulator-project$ firebase init emulators

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /home/user/src/firebase-emulator-project

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing within an existing Firebase project directory


=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, using my-existing-project.

=== Emulators Setup
? Which Firebase emulators do you want to set up? Press Space to select emulators, then Enter to confirm your choices. (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
user@devmachine:~/src/firebase-emulator-project$ firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.

Error: No emulators to start, run firebase init emulators to get started.
user@devmachine:~/src/firebase-emulator-project$
```

EDIT: Just to recap for people who might struggle with reading...

1. run *firebase init emulators*
2. select my existing project from the list of projects.
3. Select 'firestore' and 'auth' emulators to init.
4. firebase cli outputs "Firebase Initialization Complete!", and indicates no errors.
5. run *firebase emulators:start* , firebase cli outputs error *Error: No emulators to start, run firebase init emulators to get started.*.

I expected the emulators to start.

Comment: If you have a bug to report, you should file that on GitHub with the specific steps you take to reproduce the issue from scratch.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson I have no clue yet if it is a bug or being used incorrectly.

Comment: Without your specific steps from scratch, it's hard to say.  I'll point out that you're not working from scratch because the output says "firebaserc already has a default project, using my-existing-project".  You already ran init once to get to this point.  If your main point is that this isn't working the way you expect, you should also state your expectations, and how they are not being met.

Comment: @DougStevenson I literally gave the specific steps and they are listed in the output as well. What more could I provide?

Comment: Start by assuming that all I have is the CLI installed and a terminal prompt open.  What next?  Create a new directory?  It looks like you're working in "src/firebase-emulator-project".  Did you newly create that, or was it pre-existing? Your output suggests that you've done some stuff ahead of running the CLI.  Try creating a new space from scratch so we know you aren't working with an existing project that might have some prior config.  Also, what version of the CLI are you working with?  On what platform?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I'm facing exactly the same problem